# SQL Alert: 020 - SSPI handshake failure. Tracking the cause?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have done my best to find an article that answers this question but I have not had much luck.

I manage the database across three domains. One domain has the ability to access the other two, but without a trusted connection (SQL traffic through firewall using SQL credentials). I have started getting a lot of SSPI handshake failures in my logs (and as such alerts). I know that a percentage of them are my fellow developers forgetting to use SQL Auth and the server legitimately failing to authenticate.

However I also believe that there is an application out there (or an ODBC setting, authenticated excel report, etc) that is causing some of the errors. I have tracked the problem down to our RDP farm, but not to the root application/etc.

My question is: How can I determine the application/remote-user/something that is causing the SSPI error so that I can resolve it once and for-all!

Comment: I would suggest to run a [**server side trace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx) that will help you find out in detail as to what is causing those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you get the `SSPI` notification (or from the error log ), you will see the `IP` address from which the app\user tried to connect. The `IP` may be internal or external.

Just launch the command line and type:

```
NSlookup IP
```

(using the IP address from the log). This will give you the hostname from which the connection request came.

Comment: Paul. Unfortunately the IP is always one of our TS farm! So I expect it is a single user who is being re-assigned around the farm. Short of running a ss-trace and just waiting for it to happen I dont know how else to locate the app.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a profiler trace or an extended events session, and even then it may not have the application and/or username.

You may need to run an ODBC trace on the TS servers and see what's logged in there.